# checking pymongo driver details

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

How to check the pymongo driver is c compiled or not ?
what I want to know weather the pymongo driver I'm using is compliled using 'c' if not i want know to how to compile it and use it, I looking for more faster mongo driver options for python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if your PyMongo driver was installed with the C extensions using [`has_c()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/#pymongo.has_c):

```
>>> import pymongo 
>>> pymongo.has_c() 
True 
>>> import bson 
>>> bson.has_c() 
True
```

If either of those are `False`, you could re-install PyMongo with the C extensions enabled for better performance.